# Haskell - Compiler not unregisterised, so ignoring -C

Tags: c, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to compile Haskell code (.hs) into C code (.c) on my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

These are the contents of the `myLast.hs` file:

```
myLast []     = error("Please provide a non-empty list!")
myLast [x]    = x
myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs

main = do print $ myLast [1,2,3,4]
```

I ran the following command:

```
ghc -C myLast.hs
```

And got the following output:

```
on the commandline: Warning:
  Compiler not unregisterised, so ignoring -C
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( myLast.hs, myLast.o )
Linking 1_to_10 ...
```

Following files were generated:

- myLast.o
- myLast.hi
- myLast

I don't quite understand the output message. How can I fix this?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do want to compile to C? Compiling via c is disabled by default (it has to be enabled at compile time of GHC itself) in recent GHC versions.

Comment: This page provides a little more info https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/code-generators.html. It sounds like you need a GHC binary that was set to be "unregisterised" when it was compiled.